# Changing values on the edges of an array in NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am to create an array using only NumPy tools. There it is:

```
[[2 2 2 2 2]
 [2 1 1 1 2]
 [2 1 1 1 2]
 [2 1 1 1 2]
 [2 2 2 2 2]]
```

That is my code:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.ones((5, 5), dtype = int)
x[0, :] = 2
x[4, :] = 2
x[:, 0] = 2
x[:, 4] = 2
print(x)
```

I wonder if it is possible to create an array like this in an easier (shorter) way?

Answer (score 9):

**Approach #1**

Initialize with `2s` (edge values) and assign `1s` in middle portion -

```
x = 2*np.ones((5, 5), dtype = int)
x[1:-1,1:-1] = 1
```

**Approach #2**

Another *short* way -

```
x = np.ones((5, 5), dtype = int)
x[:,[0,-1]] = x[[0,-1]] = 2
```

**Approach #3**

One-liner with `2D` convolution -

```
In [302]: from scipy.signal import convolve2d

In [303]: (convolve2d(np.ones((5,5)), np.ones((3,3)),'same')<9)+1
Out[303]: 
array([[2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [2, 1, 1, 1, 2],
       [2, 1, 1, 1, 2],
       [2, 1, 1, 1, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]])
```

Comment: Thanks! That will definitely help :)

Answer (score 6):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.ones((5, 5))
b = np.pad(a[1:-1,1:-1], pad_width=((1, 1), (1, 1)), mode='constant', 
constant_values=2)
print b
```

Answer (score 3):

```
x = numpy.full((5,5), 2, dtype=int)
x[1:-1,1:-1] = 1
```